# How to split a string while keeping a count of the different delimiters?

Tags: java, string, list, dfa

So the input looks like this {q1,q2},{a,b},{[q1:a:q2],[q2:b:q2]},q1,{q2}
A DFA pretty much.

What I would like to do is split it through the comma, brackets, and colon. then print out the results individually (ie. everything in the curly brackets have their own method).

Example:

**Part1** = q1 q2

**Part2** = a b

**Part3** = q1 goes to q2 with a

q2 goes to q2 with b

**Part4** = q1

**Part5** = q2

What I was thinking was keeping a count of curly braces and if the count of curly braces =1,3,5, etc... they will execute those methods accordingly.

Problem is, when I use it as a string, I have no way of making sure it will consider **"q1"** as one string rather than **"q"** and **"1"**

When I split the string by using **.split(\s*,\s*|\{|\}|\[|\])** it will take those characters off and I can no longer keep count of them.

Or should I just keep the curly braces, print a substring (taking off the curly brace), once it sees a close curly brace it will move to the next method.

What I've tried:

Splitting the string and storing into a list

```
List<String> listDFA = Arrays.asList(DFA.split("\\s*,\\s*|\\{|\\}|\\[|\\]"));
```

Starting DFA

```
for (index = 0; index<size; index++){
     if (curlyBrackets.contains(listDFA.get(index))){ //curlyBrackets has "{}"
        System.out.println("curly"); // just a test if it sees a curly will omit later
     }

     System.out.println(index); // again a test wanted to see what was being indexed
     System.out.println(listDFA.get(index));
  }
```

What I wanted to try:

```
for (index = 0; index <size; index++){
     if (curlyBrackets.contains(DFA.substring(index, index+1))){
        curly++;
        if (curly == 1){
           index++;
           states(DFA);
        }
     }
}
```

And states() is:

```
public static void states (String DFA){
  //List<String> stateQ = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(DFA.split(" , "))); // I tried creating the list here, but then there would be a couple of incosistent variable such as index and size.
  lineVector = DFA.split(",");
  int size = lineVector.length;
  while(lineVector(index) != '}'){
     System.out.println(stateQ[index]); //DFA.charAt(index) lineVector[index] was trying either or...
     index++;
  }
  curly++;
```

Comment: regex doesn't parse, it matches. you need a parser.

Comment: @ChristianJonassen updated the post, thanks!

Comment: The string you are scanning demands a context-free grammar tool, not a regular-expression tool (DFA). You need a parser (DPDA: deterministic pushdown automaton).

Answer (score 0):

I guess some kind of a hot-fix for the problem, but I still split the string using comma as a delimiter (instead of the brackets).

```
List<String> listDFA = Arrays.asList(DFA.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
```

Therefore making each content of the string be associated with an index (brackets are attached to the nearest non-comma). Then store that index into a string.

```
String currString = listDFA.get(index);
```

Then see if any part of that string has a curly bracket

```
if (currString.indexOf('{') != -1 || currString.indexOf('}') != -1 )
```

And once it matches the curly bracket condition, execute that block

```
if (curly <= 2){
           Q.add(currString);
     }
```

Now all I have to figure out is how to do that with square brackets since I have to store those to a 2D array